# Question on the Grid View tutorial “res/drawable/ “ directory

Tags: android, eclipse

The tutoriel in question is
“http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html”

The Tutorial asks that you
1- Create a new project named HelloGridView. In eclipse **(OK)**
2- Find some images or download the ones at
    “http://developer.android.com/shareables/sample_images.zip”
    I downloaded the .ZIP file and extracted the images **(OK)**
3- Save the image files into the project's res/drawable/ directory. **(QUESTION!)**

When I expand the tree view that eclipse has created for this project, I do not see any directory labeled drawable, but instead see 3 choices (drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi & drawable-mdpi)

HelloGridView
    - res
        - - drawable-hdpi
        - - drawable-ldpi
        - - drawable-mdpi
        - - layout
        - - values

Choices/Ideas that went threw my mind
a- Maker another directory under “res” called drawable?
b- Just pop them into any of the three already existing directories labeled drawable-?dpi
c- Since I just upgraded to the new eclipse (on 2/4/11) maybe the tutorial and eclipse are out of sync, and I should just wait a while for an updated tutorial?

Comments, Ideas or Pointers to documentation or other already answered questions welcome.

I did search Stack Overflow and found lots of questions on the Grid View tutorial, but none seemed to address this particular problem.
-=-=-=

Also – When (and since this is my 3rd attempt at the Grid View tutorial,and I'm afraid it is more likely WHEN then IF) I have more questions on this tutorial, should I post separate questions, OR just extend this question for each problem I encounter?

Thanks for any help 
Joe

Comment: Kindly provide your requirement clearly

Comment: Guess I'm a bit frustrated. Sorry. The tutorial (seems to) indicate that there should be a directory created by eclipse, under HelloGridView/res called "drawable". and when I look at eclipse's storage tree for the class, under HelloGridView/res I see 3 directories that start with drawable+ some extra text (-hdpi -ldpi -mdpi). so the directory tree I'm seeing does not match the tutorial. and at this point I'm not familiar enough with the tool set to know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the purposes of a tutorial, just create a directory called drawable.

If you needed to customize your graphics for different devices with different characteristics (in this case, the pixel density of the screen - high DPI, medium DPI. or low DPI), that's when you would use the pre-built directories.